# reversing the order of a circular deque C

Tags: c, linked-list, deque

Ok, so I'm working on an assignment where you have to build a circular deque in C. I have all of the functions implemented and I'm in the process of testing them. Everything was good until the 'reverse' function.

I thought this would be easy, you create a new link, hook it up in place of the Sentinel. Kill the old sentinel and then set the sentinel for the deque to the new link.

However, when I run this I get a malloc error, and since I'm new to C, I'm not sure how to debug.

--------ERROR-------

### prog(10346) malloc: *** error for object 0x7faf13c03920: pointer being freed was not allocated set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include "cirListDeque.h"

/* Double Link Struture */
struct DLink {
    TYPE value;/* value of the link */
    struct DLink *next;/* pointer to the next link */
    struct DLink *prev;/* pointer to the previous link */
};

# define TYPE_SENTINEL_VALUE DBL_MAX 


/* ************************************************************************
 Deque ADT based on Circularly-Doubly-Linked List WITH Sentinel
 ************************************************************************ */

struct cirListDeque {
    int size;/* number of links in the deque */
    struct DLink *Sentinel; /* pointer to the sentinel */
};
/* internal functions prototypes */
struct DLink* _createLink (TYPE val);
void _addLinkAfter(struct cirListDeque *q, struct DLink *lnk, struct DLink *newLnk);
void _removeLink(struct cirListDeque *q, struct DLink *lnk);



/* ************************************************************************
    Deque Functions
************************************************************************ */

/* Initialize deque.

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null
    post:   q->backSentinel is allocated and q->size equals zero
*/
void _initCirListDeque (struct cirListDeque *q) 
{
    struct DLink* lnk = (struct DLink*)malloc(sizeof(struct DLink));
    assert(lnk != 0);   //sentinel made
    q->Sentinel = lnk;
    q->Sentinel->next = q->Sentinel->prev = q->Sentinel;
    q->size = 0;
}

/*
 create a new circular list deque
 */
struct cirListDeque *createCirListDeque()
{
    struct cirListDeque* newCL = malloc(sizeof(struct cirListDeque));
    _initCirListDeque(newCL);
    return(newCL);
}


/* Create a link for a value.

    param:  val     the value to create a link for
    pre:    none
    post:   a link to store the value
*/
struct DLink * _createLink (TYPE val)
{
    struct DLink* lnk = (struct DLink*) malloc(sizeof(struct DLink));
    lnk->value = val;
    return(lnk);

}

/* Adds a link after another link

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    param:  lnk     pointer to the existing link in the deque
    param:  newLnk  pointer to the new link to add after the existing link
    pre:    q is not null
    pre:    lnk and newLnk are not null
    post:   the new link is added into the deque after the existing link
*/
void _addLinkAfter(struct cirListDeque *q, struct DLink *lnk, struct DLink *newLnk)
{
    lnk->next->prev = newLnk;       //right connects to new
    newLnk->next = lnk->next;       //new connect to right
    newLnk->prev = lnk;             //new connect to left
    lnk->next = newLnk;             //left connect to new
    q->size++;
}

/* Adds a link to the back of the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    param:  val     value for the link to be added
    pre:    q is not null
    post:   a link storing val is added to the back of the deque
*/
void addBackCirListDeque (struct cirListDeque *q, TYPE val) 
{
    struct DLink* lnk = _createLink(val);
    _addLinkAfter(q, q->Sentinel->prev, lnk);
}

/* Adds a link to the front of the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    param:  val     value for the link to be added
    pre:    q is not null
    post:   a link storing val is added to the front of the deque
*/
void addFrontCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q, TYPE val)
{
    struct DLink* lnk = _createLink(val);
    _addLinkAfter(q, q->Sentinel, lnk);
}

/* Get the value of the front of the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null and q is not empty
    post:   none
    ret:    value of the front of the deque
*/
TYPE frontCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q) 
{
    return q->Sentinel->next->value;
}

/* Get the value of the back of the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null and q is not empty
    post:   none
    ret:    value of the back of the deque
*/
TYPE backCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    return q->Sentinel->prev->value;
}

/* Remove a link from the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    param:  lnk     pointer to the link to be removed
    pre:    q is not null and q is not empty
    post:   the link is removed from the deque
*/
void _removeLink(struct cirListDeque *q, struct DLink *lnk)
{
    //assert(!isEmptyList(lst));
    lnk->next->prev = lnk->prev;    //connect right link to left link
    lnk->prev->next = lnk->next;    //connect left link to right link
    q->size--;
    free(lnk);
}

/* Remove the front of the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null and q is not empty
    post:   the front is removed from the deque
*/
void removeFrontCirListDeque (struct cirListDeque *q) {
    _removeLink(q, q->Sentinel->next);
}


/* Remove the back of the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null and q is not empty
    post:   the back is removed from the deque
*/
void removeBackCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    _removeLink(q, q->Sentinel->prev);
}

/* De-allocate all links of the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    none
    post:   All links (including backSentinel) are de-allocated
*/
void freeCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    while (q->size > 0){
        removeFrontCirListDeque(q);
    }
    free(q->Sentinel);
}

/* Check whether the deque is empty

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null
    ret:    1 if the deque is empty. Otherwise, 0.
*/
int isEmptyCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q) {
    return q->size == 0;
}

/* Print the links in the deque from front to back

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null and q is not empty
    post:   the links in the deque are printed from front to back
*/
void printCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    struct DLink *current;
    int x = 0;
    assert(!isEmptyCirListDeque(q));

    current = q->Sentinel->next;
    while(current != q->Sentinel){
        printf("value: %f\t", current->value);
        current = current->next;
        x++;
        if (x >= 6){
            printf("\n");
            x = 0;
        }
    }
}

/* Reverse the deque

    param:  q       pointer to the deque
    pre:    q is not null and q is not empty
    post:   the deque is reversed
*/
void reverseCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    //struct DLink *temp = _createNewLink(0); //try this allocat then assign then move
    struct DLink *newSent = (struct DLink*) malloc(sizeof(struct DLink));
        newSent->next = q->Sentinel->prev;
        newSent->prev = q->Sentinel->next;
        q->Sentinel->next->prev = newSent;
        q->Sentinel->prev->next = newSent;
        free(q->Sentinel);
        q->Sentinel = newSent;

/* A different approach that didn't work.
        temp->next = q->Sentinel->prev;
            q->Sentinel->prev = q->Sentinel->next;
            q->Sentinel->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);*/
}
```

Comment: Did you try to "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"?

Comment: I didn't know where to find malloc_error_break. I tried setting a break point and watching the link get created. As I stepped through it values were not doing what they were supposed to but I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here, but thanks to the posters, the debugging tips made this answer possible.

My logic was flawed.

I thought that if you reversed the direction of the sentinel you could reverse the order of the circular list. However, even if you change all four of the links to the sentinel, the surrounding links prev and next fields point in the wrong direction.

To fix this I created a new deque with this code:

```
    void reverseCirListDeque(struct cirListDeque *q)
{
    struct cirListDeque* newQ = createCirListDeque();
    while(!isEmptyCirListDeque(q)){
        addBackCirListDeque(newQ, backCirListDeque(q));
        removeBackCirListDeque(q);
    }
    q->Sentinel = newQ->Sentinel;
    q->size = newQ->size;
    free(newQ);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For debugging C programs, **gdb** is the best. It'd do you a lot of good to learn how to use it. The documentation is at http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/

If you really want a GUI front end (and "gdb -tui" is unacceptable), try **ddd** or **insight**.

A debugger will help you walk along as your program runs and will enable you to inspect your data structure at every step so that you can find our the first time it gets corrupted.

Comment: Eclipse is not traditionally used for C debugging. Maybe it is good for C, but Eclipse was developed as more of a Java programmers tool. I don't have experience using Eclipse for C debugging. **ddd** has a pretty nice data visualizer you might find useful for looking at your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to debugging this would be to add printfs. For example, after the malloc call in `_initCirListDeque` add this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "dbg malloc sentinel %p\n", (void *)lnk);
```

Add a similar line after the malloc in `reverseCirListDeque`.

Then add similar printf lines before the calls to free in `_removeLink`, `freeCirListDeque` and `reverseCirListDeque`.

When you run the code, you should see on the standard error the pointer addresses being malloc'd and freed. You should be able to see if the value that fails to be free'd was already freed (my guess is that this is what's happening).

The purpose of the word `dbg` is to make it easy to search for these debug printfs and delete them once you've found the bug.

Comment: Even better is to leave the debug prints in your code for the next time you need to debug or inspect the code. Strongly consider using a debug macro like `#define DEBUG_PRINT(args...) fprintf(stderr, args)` or `#define DEBUG_PRINT(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)`.